# Spinner Android Value member and Display member

Tags: android, android-spinner

spinner normally displays only one string in my case I want to assign IDpersonne and Name,
and the spinner must show me the name.
and when I get the selected item , i have to get the ID.
How can i do it ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you have your items arranged in arraylist of HashMap
Create your adapter as follows:

```
ArrayAdapter<> adapter=new ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item_1, listItems)
{
   public Object getItem(int position)
   {
       HashMap<String, String> tblItem=listItems.get(position);
       return tblItem.get("NAME"); 
   }

   public int getCount()
   {
       listItems.size();
   }
}
```

Set this adapter to spinner:

```
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

get an Item on selection by using:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener()
{
     public void onItemSelected(AdapterView adapterView, View view, int position, long id)
     {
            HashMap<String, String> tblItem=listItems.get(position);
            //Use this map to get other values in list
     }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use an [Adapter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/binding.html). Basically, an adapter is a wrapper of your data that generate items to show in a Spinner or a ListView etc.

There are several implementation of adapters, and you can create your own if none of them fits your data structure.